# sed regex not matching as expected

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to manipulate a yum repofile with sed and its not working as expected. The file looks something like this:

```
[repo id]
name = value
name = value
[repo id]
name = value
name = value
```

This may not be the best approach but I am still wanting to understand why it doesn't work...

First I take the repo file and turn it into one big string:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/:::/g' $repofile |
```

Then, **and this is the part that isn't working**, I want to match the specific repo I am looking for and trim off the rest of the file. I am doing this by matching the opening [ followed by the string containing the correct repo id. Then I want to match everything else following that up until the next opening [ in the file:

```
sed "s/^.*\(\[${repoid}\].*\[\).*/\1/" >~/trimed_repo
```

Then I put the newlines back in and continue modifying with awk later.

```
sed 's/:::/\n/g' ~/trimed_repo >~/expanded_repo
```

The problem I am having is that my regex seems to skip all the next opening [ in the file after the one paired with the $repoid and only matches the last opening [ in the file.

I tried using a "lazy quantifier" but it stopped the regex from matching at all. Like This:

```
sed "s/^.*\(\[${repoid}\].*?\[\).*/\1/" >~/trimed_repo
```

And like this:

```
sed "s/^.*\(\[${repoid}\](.*?)\[\).*/\1/" >~/trimed_repo
```

***answer****

So with some help in the comments I did this which works:

```
sed "s/^.*\(\[${repoid}\][^[]*\)\[.*/\1/" >~/trimed_repo
```

The lesson is that what I should have done was to say match everything that is not a opening [ until you find an opening [ and that will prevent the unwanted behavior.

Can someone explain why the behavior of those options is different in those two instances? .* doesn't match to the end of the file in the first instance. It stops at the next specified option. But in the second instance it doesn't stop till the last occurrence of the match.

I'm referring to my original, broken example:

```
sed "s/^.*\(\[${repoid}\].*\[\).*/\1/" >~/trimed_repo
```

Comment: With regexp you must say what you mean `.*` means zero or more of any character (including [). You need to say any character other than `[` or in other words all characters except `[` (`[^[]*`).

Comment: Thanks @potong, but why does it "work" before the variable without being too greedy? I'm trying it now.

Comment: I think it's because there's more regex after the first `.*`. Because you put the second `.*` at the end, it just matches everything single character til the end of the line whereas the first one (**I think**) stops once it finds a `[`

Comment: It is greedy it just backtracks from the last character in the string until it finds a `[` followed by `${repoid}`. So you would be better off removing the `^.*` all together.

Comment: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else you should use awk. If you post some sample input (rather than just a template for input) and expected output we can provide a clear, concise, robust solution for you in awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
[foo]
name = 3
name = 17
[bar]
name = 24
name = 5

$ awk -v id="foo" '/\[/{f=index($0,"["id"]")} f' file
[foo]
name = 3
name = 17

$ awk -v id="bar" '/\[/{f=index($0,"["id"]")} f' file
[bar]
name = 24
name = 5
```

The above just sets a flag (`f` for found) when it finds a line containing `[foo]`, for example, and clears it when it finds the next line containing a `[`. When `f` is set it prints the line.

Note also that unlike any possible sed solution, the above will be unaffected by RE metacharacters or delimiter characters in the search variable (e.g. `., ?, *, +, /, (, etc.`) since it is looking for a STRING not a regular expression.

Comment: That is a MUCH better technique than what I was using I'm going to do it this way. How do you feel about the approach of turning the file into a single string? It's the only way I could think of to deal with the format of the file. I tried to avoid sending it to sed and then awk and just get it done with awk.

Comment: That'd be fine, it just takes more memory and can't be written as concisely as the approach I used. If you want to do it, to read the whole file as a string in GNU awk you use `awk -v RS='^$' 'script' file`, in other awks you'd built up the string by concatenation lines as they're read and then processing the string in the END section. There's still no place for sed in doing anything involving multiple lines though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ranges to extract the matching part from your repo file.

```
sed -ne "/\[${repoid}\]/,/\[/{/\[${repoid}\]/p;/\[/!p}" $repofile > ~/trimed_repo
```